# sp_getApplock lockOwner values transaction vs session

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure that needs to be running one at a time (should not be running concurrently).

For this I am using below stored proc

```
exec @result = sys.sp_getapplock 
@Resource='Employee', @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @LockOwner= 'session', @LockTimeout = 0
```

Inside that call there is LockOwner set to '**session**' and there is also another possible value called '**transaction**'.

I do know that if I will choose transaction I need to write stored proc body within transaction.

I searched about differences between both but did not get any luck.

Can anybody please help me out what is difference between them apart from calling sp_getapplock inside transction?

I will also appreciate any best practices for solving my problem (prevent running stored procedure from concurrent execution.)

Comment: As clarification, why would you want to limit the execution of a stored proc to once only? What will happen when multiple users want to do the same thing? What is the goal of the lock, to prevent what?

Comment: @BerndLinde I need to create and assign one unique random no composed of two parts 1) is random part and 2) is sequential part (e.g. ABD001, CDE002, DFD003 ....). Purpose of the stored proc is to generate this random no.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) object might work better for you than the applock solution. It acts a little like an identity column without a table and will allow you to generate the sequential part of your random number in a thread-safe way.